# Providing .Net Training to recruitment team

Tags: .net, asp.net, oop, .net-3.5

In our organization responsibility is given to me to teach .net to our recruitment team (non technical), i need to design the entire training session.

They want a training so they can filter out some of the candidates at their level.

Please give me suggestion that what i should teach them in my training ?

Comment: IMHO this is a bad idea. They will not know enough about the technology to tell good candidates from bad. Have you ever heard the saying "A little knowledge is a dangerous thing"?. This is one of those cases. After the training session they will now "know" .net, but they will have no idea of how much they do not know. You may get a perfectly capable candidate who approaches developement or speaks about development in a way they do not understand. Because they now "KNOW" .net they will assume the candidate does not, and you've filtered out a potential hire. Bad idea.

Comment: I am also agree with you and if i would be the decision authority i may scrap entire idea but it is not possible so i will clearly instruct them that they will not become .net expert due to this training and it is just to help them and filter candidate and that is the reason it is becoming difficult for me that what should be the content of the training

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it clear that:

- X years of experience with technology Y means nothing
- Personal projects experience is just as valuable (if not more) than commercial work experience.
- Screening should be focused on potential of a candidate (abiity and willingness to learn) rather than on immediate knowledge

Comment: You are right but what i am thinking like if person is having some years of experience in particular technology then he should be able to answer some fundamental questions regarding technology or the overall concept

Comment: That's never gonna work. You can't have a professional interview conducted by non-specialists. It will take them several years of intensive programming practice before they might be able to participate in an interview process.

Comment: I agree with Developer Art: The best you can do here is come up with a set of multiple choice questions. The not technical interviewer can mark these without knowing the content of the question OR the answer. Different questions can be weighted so it obvious if some basic questions were wrong but harder questions "guessed" correctly.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, don't teach them .Net since it won't help: A recruitment officer doesn't need to know the difference between a class and a struct when he/she wants to filter candidates.

What they need to know is the job requirements and the technical skills required for this job, and some "buzz words" that may help pick out the candidates.

For example: Is the job server-side oriented or client-side? Depending on the answer, give them some buzz words on that subject, so they'll know to ignore those who are more oriented to what you don't need.

In addition, I think it would help to explain them how to identify who's a "star" according to what they've already done, and is good enough to adapt to your job requirements. Not those who write "Fast and self learner" but according to their "knowledge portfolio", how versatile are their previous jobs, etc.

Good luck!

Comment: good suggestions...i was also thinking on the same line

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't do it. Recruitment team won't understand it. 
Second, the knowledge of .NET depends on the position. Sometimes candidates that are good programmer but have done .NET for a bit are better suitable than crappy programmer's that can hack stuff in .NET. Screening can be by references from the candidates previous employers.